# Format output of two functions side by side

Tags: bash

I want to format the output of two functions side by side.

Here is the example I am currently working on, including my failed attempt at the bottom.

```
#!/bin/bash

status_awsomeproject1() {
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject1 ################\e[0;37m"
    cd /home/joaoc/Projects/awsomeproject1
    git status
    cd vendor/libs
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject1-> lib-1 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-1 status
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject1-> lib-2 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-2 status
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject1-> lib-3 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-3 status
}

status_awsomeproject2() {
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject2 ################\e[0;37m"
    cd /home/joaoc/Projects/awsomeproject2
    git status
    cd vendor/libs
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject2-> lib-1 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-1 status
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject2-> lib-2 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-2 status
    echo "\e[0;33m\n################ Status awsomeproject2-> lib-3 ################\e[0;37m"
    git -C lib-3 status
}


echo "$(status_awsomeproject1) || $(status_psp)" | column -t
```

The wrap() command does what I need but does so as a single column only.

How can I achieve the desired output?

Thank you

Edit, in order provide a minimal working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

string_output1() {
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
}

string_output2() {
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
    echo "################ Example long multi-line string ################\n\n"
}


echo "$(string_output1) || $(string_output2)" | column -t
```

Comment: Added an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use temporary files, do it like below :

```
status_awsomeproject1>tmp1
status_awsomeproject2>tmp2
paste tmp1 tmp2
rm tmp1 tmp2 # Remove the temporary files after use
```

If your shell supports [[ process substitution ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) you can simplify the above to:

```
paste -d^ <(status_awsomeproject1) <(status_awsomeproject2)
```

**Edit**

You could pipe the results to awk for alignment like below :

```
paste  -d^ <(status_awsomeproject1) <(status_awsomeproject2) | \
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\^"}{printf "%-10s %s\n",$1,$2}' 2>/dev/null
```

First you have to find a suitable delimiter that has less/no chance to appear in the output of the functions. I have chosen `^`. Then, use this delimiter as the awk field separator and use `awk printf` widths to control the width.

---

**Note:**
I have set `awk printf` width to 10 but you need to change it according to the expected length of output from the function. Trial and error, but nbd though.

Comment: Your description is wrong! process substitution will **not** create a temporary file!

Comment: @hek2mgl :  I just said `appear` . Please explain.

Comment: The also don't *appear* as temporary files. The appear as a FIFO, like the bash manual I've added says. And they don't just appear as a FIFO, they are in fact a FIFO.

Comment: @hek2mgl : Okay, rollbacked. By the way, I didn't mean `appear` would create files. In fact it is FIFO, but I felt that edit would be a bit misguiding..

Comment: Pretty good, this does in fact show the text side by side, how would I got about aligning it so that I can make two columns with the result ? (the two halves may or may not have TABS or other characters)

Comment: @JoaoCarlos : Updated.

Comment: @sjsam Added "fold -w 55" to word wrap the output. ```paste  -d^ <(status_awsomeproject1 | fold -w 55) <(status_awsomeproject2 | fold -w 55) | \
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\^"}{printf "%-70s %s\n",$1,$2}' 2>/dev/null```
Looks a bit better :)

Comment: My solution before yours was ```status_awsomeproject1 | fold -w 55 | > tmp1
status_awsomeproject2 | fold -w 55 | > tmp2
paste -d $'!!!' tmp1 tmp2 | column -t -s $'!!!'  | column -t -s $'!!!' 
rm tmp1 tmp2``` But it still suffers from the same problem

Comment: @JoaoCarlos How about adding `fold` after `awk`?